# Laravel вывод ошибки api

Tags: laravel, api

Подскажите пишу api на laravel 5.5, если ввожу не правильный логин или пароль ошибку выводит ввиде html страницы

middleware:

```html
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthenticateOnceWithBasicAuth 
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return Auth::onceBasic('username') ? response()->json(['message'=>'Auth failed'],401)  : $next($request);
    }
}
```

Делал проверку в App\Exceptions\Handler, не помогает вывести json ошибку:

```html
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException){
            return redirect()->back()->with('serverError','Token expired please try to submit form again');
        }
     elseif ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson())
    {
        $message = [$exception->getMessage()];

        if($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
            $message = $exception->errors();
        }

        $json = [
            'success' => false,
            'error' => [
                'messages' => $message,
            ],
        ];
        
        return response()->json($json, 401);
    }
        
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Comment: какие заголовки запроса?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в заголовок запроса `Accept: application/json`

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, есть идеи еще?